# Telerik Kendo Grid Doesn't Display Value Properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

i'm new to kendo UI and currently learning about custom editor.
My Problem is i managed to get my editor template working in edit mode and populate the data just fine, but somehow it won't save the value to the display grid

I Retreive all my data from API.

**UPDATE:**
i've managed to properly save the value from the custom editor template to the controller and it works just fine, but using clientTemplate won't display the correct value from what i select in the dropdown, and only show a string

[DropDown Only Display A String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3wxg.png)

my setup code is like this

```
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<SalesOrderDetailVM>()
            .Name("list-detail")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Product).ClientTemplate("\\#=Product.ProductId\\#").Title("Products");
                columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
                columns.Bound(c => c.UnitPrice);
            })
            .Editable(GridEditMode.InCell)
            .ToolBar(tool =>
            {
                tool.Create();
                tool.Save();
            }
            )
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Batch(true)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
                    model.Field(p => p.Product);
                })
                .Create(act => act.Action("DetailCell_Create","SalesOrder"))
            )
)
```

DDLProduct.cshtml:

```
@model AAF.WEB.MVC.ViewModels.ProductVM

@(
        Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                        .DataValueField("ProductId")
                        .DataTextField("ProductName")
                        .OptionLabel("Select Product")
                        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["products"])
)
```

[Edit Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT4F6.png) 
[DisplayMode / Out of Product Edit Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ML80.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use template method to acheive dropdown with kendo grid.

GridForeignKey.cshtml - it should placed in shared folder or EditorTemplates
    @model object

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

In your kendo grid please change like below

```
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<AAF.WEB.MVC.ViewModels.SalesOrderDetailVM>()
            .Name("list-detail")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
               columns.ForeignKey(c => c.ProductId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Products"], "ProductId", "ProductName").Title("Products");
                columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
                columns.Bound(c => c.UnitPrice);
            })
            .Editable(GridEditMode.InCell)
            .ToolBar(tool =>
            {
                tool.Create();
                tool.Save();
            }
            )
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(false)
            )
)
```

You can set the products data to view data. using this method you can save the product id.

Thanks

Comment: using foreign key did work but it doesn't display & save the value to the grid. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Okay after i frustrated for many hours, finally found the solution

the solution is to add a defaultvalue to the passed model in the grid

```
.Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
                    model.Field(p => p.Product).DefaultValue(
                            ViewData["defaultProduct"] as ProductVM
                        );
                })
```

and pass the data from the controller

```
// Function that get data from API

ViewData["products"] = products;
ViewData["defaultProduct"] = products.First();
```